# Does $\log_2 \sqrt[4]4$ exist?

Tags: logarithms

Tomorrow I have an exam about graphics and log operations.
Our teacher gave us a paper with exercises to practice and one of the exercises is:

> $\log_2 \sqrt[4]4$

I couldn't find the solution. My private teacher helped me but he didn't find the solution.

We don't think this log has a solution.

- Does a solution exist for this?
- How do you do that if there is a solution?

*The exercise says the log can't be solved using a calculator.*

*Is my first question in* Mathematics.*If I am doing something wrong, please, tell me what I am doing wrong.*

Comment: **HINT**: $\sqrt[4]{4}=4^{\frac{1}{4}}=(2^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you mean the logarithm to the base $2$, i.e. that your problem is to calculate:
$$\log_2(\sqrt[4]{4}).$$
Let's recall a rule for taking roots: Suppose $x>0$, and that $n$ is an integer. Then it is true that
$$\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{1/n}.$$
I want to use this in your problem for the expression inside the logarithm. We get that
$$\sqrt[4]{4} = 4^{1/4}.$$
Next, let's recall a rule for using logarithms. If $\log$ is any logarithm, $x>0$, and $a>0$, then
$$\log(x^a) = a\log(x),$$
i.e. I can take the exponent from inside of the logarithm and pull it out. Using these two rules, I can rewrite your problem as
$$\log_2(\sqrt[4]{4}) = \log_2(4^{1/4})=\frac{1}{4}\log_2(4).$$
It remains to do something about the expression $\log_2(4)$, but we can readily see what this is: $\log_2(4)$ is equal to the number $x$, such that $2^x=4$, which is just $x=2$. Thus $\log_2(4) = 2$, and so
$$\log_2(\sqrt[4]{4}) = \frac{1}{4}\log_2(4) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot 2 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Oh, thanks! That was useful!